# Remove all white-spaces in string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

this drives me nuts - Im trying to remove all white-spaces in a string, and nothing seems to work. what am i doing wrong?

This is what im trying with at the moment:

```
$(".unfoldedlabel a").text().replace(/ /g,'');
```

HTML:

```
<span class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories/Service & Support</a></span>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not updating the text in HTML. After removing the spaces, the innerText in DOM need to be updated.

Use [.text(function)](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function):

```
$(".unfoldedlabel a").text(function (index, oldText) {
    return oldText.replace(/\s+/g, '');
});
```

```js
$(".unfoldedlabel a").text(function(i, t) {
  return t.replace(/\s+/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories/Service & Support</a></span>
```

Comment: I'm nitpicking here but to remove "_all whitespaces_" the regex should probably be `/\s/g` instead :)

Comment: @Andreas Yes, used `\s+` to replace all spaces

Answer (score 1):

And another solution is:

```
var s=$(".unfoldedlabel a").text();
$(".unfoldedlabel a").text(s.replace(/ +?/g, ''));//or /\s+?/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code -

```
$(function() {
  var changeText = $(".unfoldedlabel a").text().replace(/ /g,'');

  $(".unfoldedlabel a").text(changeText);
});
```